# Why I can not get Map element by key?

Tags: javascript

First I fill one Map as:

```
let words = new Map();
let response = [{ 4000: { text: "Ok" } }, { 5000: { text: "Ok" } }];

response.forEach(d => {
    let objectKey = Object.keys(d).pop();
    words.set(objectKey, d[objectKey]);
});
```

Then I create a new map and set by key prev Map `words`:

```
let dict = new Map();
dict.set('en', words);
```

Why I can not get value by chain call?

```
console.log(dict.get("en").get(4000));
```

Comment: Seems it should be as string key `4000`

Comment: The title sounds ambiguous. Can you please edit the title to be more descriptive for the benefit of other users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objectKey` is `"4000"` and not `4000` (of type `number`)

This should work:

```
dict.get("en").get("4000")
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Key_equality):

> Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as a key

And

> Key equality is based on the `sameValueZero` algorithm: NaN is considered the same as NaN (even though NaN !== NaN) and all other values are considered equal **according to the semantics of the === operator**

So, "4000" and 4000 are treated as separate keys.

```js
const map = new Map

map.set("4000", "value1")
map.set(4000, "value2")

console.log([...map.entries()])
```

When object's properties are accessed, it is *coerced to string*. But with `Map` no such thing is done

Comment: So, then how to get value by string and number key ?(same key)

Comment: @OPV Are you certain that `let objectKey = Object.keys(d).pop()` returns a number like key? In which case you can parse it to a number `+Object.keys(d).pop()`

Answer (score 1):

> The keys of an `Object` are [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

-- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

When you get a key from an object (i.e.: `let objectKey = Object.keys(d).pop();` ) it comes as a string and not as a number as you had originally defined in your object.

You need to convert it to a number for it to work as you had intended:

```
let objectKey = Number(Object.keys(d).pop());
```

Working example:

```js
let words = new Map();
let response = [{ 4000: { text: "Ok" } }, { 5000: { text: "Ok" } }];

response.forEach(d => {
    let objectKey = Number(Object.keys(d).pop());
    words.set(objectKey, d[objectKey]);
});

let dict = new Map();
dict.set('en', words);

console.log(dict.get("en").get(4000));
```

On a side note, you could also simplify the process in which you create the `words` map object.

```
const words = new Map(response.map(d => {
  const [id, val] = Object.entries(d).shift();
  return [Number(id), val];
}));
```